# htaccess - load index.html from subdirectory

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a index.html file in a subdirectory in my htdocs folder. Something like:

> example.com/htdocs/web/index.html

Now I want it to load automatically if I call `example.com` but I don't want to move the `index.html` file to the root directory. Is there a way to solve this with the .htacess file?

Something like:

"if example.com is requestes, load content from example.com/web/index.html"

I haven't worked so much with .htaccess files and couln't find something that solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the AliasMatch directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch) for this. For example:

```
AliasMatch "^/$" "/var/www/htdocs/web/index.html"
```

Comment: I've tried that but I only get a 500 back --> AliasMatch "^/$" "/var/www/example.com/htdocs/web/index.html"

Comment: @dwdawdawdaw — 500 just means "Something went wrong". You need to read your error log to find out what.

Answer (score 0):

try this .htaccess configuration

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /var/www/htdocs/web/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```